# In linux, how can I test whether the output of a program is going to a live terminal or to a file?

Tags: linux, terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal, konsole

When you use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) it seems to magically know whether standard out is going through a pipe or into a file vs when it is being displayed to the console.  For example, if you have colors enabled and you do

```
git status
```

it will colorize the output for different categories of files being listed.  However, if you do

```
git status | less
```

or

```
git status > status.txt
```

it removes the [linux color formatting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) and you only see plain, uncolored text.

How does `git` detect whether the output of its commands are going to file vs going to the terminal?

Comment: I don't think that this should be on superuser, as the OP is really looking for is how does the program ie. git detects where it is being redirected or not.

Comment: I agree with @tommieb75 it is an API question, not a how do I admin question.

Comment: By the way, if you weren't just curious, and you were asking this because you wanted to have colorized *and* paged output from git, you can mess with `git config` settings like `core.pager` (less) and `color.pager` (true).  http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`isatty(int fd)` will check whether the fd refers to a terminal or something else.  It's part of `unistd.h` in the GNU C library.

Man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty

As an aside: if you want to read from a program using another program, but you want to fool `isatty` into thinking that your program is a human, there is a way to do that.  You can use a [pseudo-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) (pty).  This technique is used by [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), for example.

Answer (score 8):

This is a C Code to demonstrate how to detect if standard output is redirected:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (!isatty(fileno(stdout))){
      fprintf(stdout, "argv, argc, someone is redirecting me elsewhere...\n");
      return 1;
    }
    /* rest of C code here... */
}
```

That is how git knows whether the output is going to the terminal or to a file.

Answer (score 3):

Can confirm that's what git relies on:

```
$ grep -ir "isatty" ./*
./builtin-commit.c:     if (isatty(0))
./builtin-config.c:         stdout_is_tty = isatty(1);
./builtin-pack-objects.c:   progress = isatty(2);
./builtin-prune-packed.c:   int opts = isatty(2) ? VERBOSE : 0;
./builtin-revert.c: if (isatty(0))
./builtin-shortlog.c:   if (!nongit && !rev.pending.nr && isatty(0))
./builtin-unpack-objects.c: quiet = !isatty(2);
./color.c:      stdout_is_tty = isatty(1);
./compat/winansi.c: if (!isatty(fileno(stream)))
./compat/winansi.c: if (!isatty(fileno(stream)))
./pack-redundant.c: if (!isatty(0)) {
./pager.c:  if (!isatty(1))
./pager.c:  if (isatty(2))
./remote-curl.c:    options.progress = !!isatty(2);
./transport.c:  args.no_progress = args.quiet || (!transport->progress && !isatty(1));
./transport-helper.c:   int no_progress = v < 0 || (!t->progress && !isatty(1));
./wt-status.c:   * will have checked isatty on stdout).
```

Run against the git source tree.

Note that fds 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr by default, but these can of course be re-directed or closed (typically if you are a daemon you close your file descriptors and re-open the ones you want).

Answer (score 3):

From a shell script, use the `-t` test flag applied to the file descriptor 0 (standard input).

Examples:

```
# Any Bourne-style shell
[ -t 0 ] && echo This is a terminal

# Modern interactive shells: ksh, bash, zsh
[[ -t 0 ]] && echo This is a terminal
```